# Do we really need the [vim] tag?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-completed, tags

Theoretically, [vim](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vim) is supposed to be used to specify that the question is specific to *the* Vim, that is, Vi IMproved by Bram Moolenaar.

However, it appears that this is rarely the case in practice, and I don't think it will be the case in the future either.

Almost all questions tagged [vim](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vim) are not actually specific to Vim itself, and new users shouldn't be expected to know the exact usage guidelines that are rigidly expected.

So, a proposal: Burninate and blacklist [vim](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vim). Nothing good can come of it.

(Secondary proposal: Possibly create a new tag [vanilla-vim](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vanilla-vim) or something along those lines, to signify questions that are indeed *specific* to only Vim, such as [What is Neovim? How is it different from Vim? And why should I care?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/34/88).)

Comment: Yes! And we should have [tag:vanilla-vi] as well for the prepreprepredecessor.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There've been a couple of other discussions on this:

- [Should we have separate tags [vi] and [vim]?](https://vi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1/should-we-have-separate-tags-vi-and-vim)
- [Should questions and answers assume the use of Vim?](https://vi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4/should-questions-and-answers-assume-the-use-of-vim)

It's becoming apparent that neither [vi](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vi) nor [vim](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vim) is likely to be used at all consistently here. Meanwhile, there *is* considerable value in encouraging folks to use tags that reflect the platform they're using, *in cases where this is relevant* - having tags that correspond to broad families of editors thwarts this goal. I think [yo' said it best](https://vi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1/should-we-have-separate-tags-vi-and-vim#comment18_2):

> Having experience from the TeX - LaTeX site, I would suggest not: the B.J.'s original should get a longer tag name, otherwise people never use it correctly. We ended with tex-core and plain-tex, and we blacklisted latex for question about LaTeX itself in favour of latex-project. I would suggest original-vi for the B.J.'s version.

This is quickly becoming apparent in how folks are using [vim](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vim). Therefore, I've done as you requested and burned + blacklisted this tag, with the following warning shown if someone tries to use it:

[image]

Comment: +1 I would just, as I see it now, prefer "vanilla" over "original" since "original" just doesn't sound good for vim.

Comment: @yo' My first interpretation of _vanilla_ would be "no plugins", not "mainline".