# Should we do something about the [untagged] tag?

Tags: discussion

I just noticed that the tag [untagged](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/untagged) as been created some days ago.

At the time I write this question is it used for two questions:

- [How can I inspire others to use vi/Vim?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/5015/1841)
- [How much money has been raised for needy children in Uganda from Vim?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/572/1841)

I feel like such a tag shouldn't exists since it would encourage user to ask off topic questions or not tag properly their questions.

On the mother site SO, the [`untagged`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/untagged) tag is used by the system and users are asked not to use it directly.

If it was only me, I would remove the tag [untagged](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/untagged), the first question should be retagged (I don't know with which tag) and the second tagged as [history-of](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/history-of).

Before doing so I wanted to check the opinion of the community.

Comment: You can't manually tag questions with this tag. [Try it](http://i.stack.imgur.com/UfHnm.png). So yeah, if you see it: retag the question ... I can't think of any good tags for these questions right now though (possibly because I have a hangover :-/)

Comment: Oh I didn't try to actually use it. I'll edit its wiki to make more clear that it is a system tag then. Good luck with the hangover ;-)

Comment: Like @Carpetsmoker I couldn't think of any good tags for those. But `history-of` is a good one for the second.

Comment: @muru: I retagged the second one. One the first one, [a user suggested](http://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/5015/how-can-i-inspire-others-to-use-vi-vim#comment7658_5015) `vim-evangelism`... I think it would fit the question but I'm really not sure our site would benefit from such a tag... (IMO the first question should have been closed anyway)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you see a question tagged [untagged](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/untagged), retag it to give it proper tags.

[untagged](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/untagged) appears under two circumstances:

- When a question is migrated and none of the tags it had on the source site exist here.
- When all the tags on a question are deleted. Tags can be deleted in two ways:

  - A tag can deleted by a Stack Exchange employee following a discussion on meta, as [`vim` was](https://vi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76/do-we-really-need-the-vim-tag).
  - There is an [automated job that removes tags that are applied to a single question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/48417/should-we-zap-the-low-occurrence-tags/48418#48418), whether the tag is needed or not, without telling anyone, and without leaving a trace. To save a tag from this tag killer, [write a tag wiki](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/127700/do-not-expire-single-use-tags-that-have-a-tag-wiki).

The two questions you cite were victims of the tag killer. They need to be retagged. If you introduce a tag that's used only on one question, make sure to write a tag wiki or the situation will repeat itself in six months.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation about the tagger killer I didn't know it existed.